# JavaScript won't update files

Tags: javascript, html, css, function

I have a few JavaScript functions that are meant to grab files for a select tag, and update them when a certain option is selected.

The files are still being retrieved by JavaScript, but I've FTP'd new options and the old ones are only showing up.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#schedGrab').change(function() {
var schedGrab = $(this).find('option:selected').text();
if (schedGrab == "English") {
    $("#schedPost").load('../start/classes.html #english');
    $("#specPost").load('../start/specs.html #english');
});
```

Comment: Please share your code or we won't be able to help you.

Comment: Are you expecting Javascript to upload/read files from a server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

`$("#schedPost").load('../start/classes.html#english');`

to

`$("#schedPost").load('../start/classes.html?'+ new Date().getTime() +'#english');`

(I think that the # is useless, but it not your problem right now).

Comment: Yeah, this could be important if your classes.html page is changing frequently. Its a good idea to add the date/time so that the page doesn't get cached the way it is.

Answer (score 0):

A few thoughts:

- I think you want to loose the spaces between the html pages and the id you're point to. eg

  index.html#something

NOT

```
index.html #something
```

- Check out http://jsfiddle.net. If you can replicate a simple, paired down version of your problem it will help us talk about. it

Comment: FTP is not the problem. The files change, but not where they need to.

Comment: Updated my answer, does that do it?